# php loop mathmatic questions

Tags: php, loops, count

Hi lets say we have this values :

```
$total = 317;
$x = 5;
$numpages = ceil($total / $x);
```

i need to loop over $total value and echo result like this

```
i=1 , numpage = 1
i=2 , numpage = 1
i=3 , numpage = 1
i=4 , numpage = 1
i=5 , numpage = 1

i=6 , numpage = 2
i=7 , numpage = 2
i=8 , numpage = 2
i=9 , numpage = 2
i=10 , numpage = 2

until....

i=317 , numpage = 64
```

i don't want to use manual if statement like this

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $total; $i++) {
if($i <= 5)
numpage = 1

if($i <= 10)
numpage = 2

}
```

becuase $x = 5; could change as i want i need formula that works with any x value 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is,

```
$total = 100; //Can be any number
$x = 5;   //Can be any number
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++) {
     if($i % $x != 0){
        $pageNo = floor($i / $x) + 1; 
     } 
     echo "Page $pageNo for value $i\n";
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/d7pVYnpe)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $total; $i++) {
 $numpage = ceil($i/5);//$ was missing 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$total  = 317;
$x      = 5;

for ($i = 0; $i <= ($total-1); $i++) 
{   
    $currentPage = floor($i / $x) + 1;
    echo 'i = '. ($i+1). ' , numpage = '.$currentPage.'<br />'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++) {
 $numpage = ceil($i/5);
    print "i = $i, numpage = $numpage"."\n";
 }
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does. Just posting code is usually not a good answer on SO

Comment: The most important here is the function `ceil` [man ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) and echo result ("\n" because i test this in console)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
$numpage = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++) {

    $numpage = (($i-1) % 5 == 0)?$numpage +1:$numpage;
    echo 'i = '.$i.' , numpage '. $numpage.'<br/>';

 }
```